# Avoid appending select with identical values?

Tags: jquery

On button first click, Select is appended with option 'one', on the next click I want to avoid append for identical values.

Below code results in appending identical values, **first-click : *one***, **second-click : *one, one, two***. Desire to avoid the repeatition of existing value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var val=["one","two","three"];
  var n=1;
  $("button").click(function(){
     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       $("select").not($("option[value='+val[i]+']")).append("<option>"+val[i]+"</option>");
     }
     n+=1;  
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you mean you want the result as: one, two, three, ... right?

Comment: Yes exactly, required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method and `:contains()` selector

```
    var select = $("select");
    //Append all in array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (select.has('option:contains("' + val[i] + '")').length == 0)
        select.append("<option>" + val[i] + "</option>");
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = ["one", "two", "three"];
  var n = 1;
  $("button").click(function() {
    var select = $("select");
    //Append all in array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (select.has('option:contains("' + val[i] + '")').length == 0)
        select.append("<option>" + val[i] + "</option>");
    }
    n += 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

---

You can remove all `option` except first, then simply append.

```
    var select = $("select");
    //Remove all except first
    select.find('option:not(:first)').remove();

    //Append all in array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      select.append("<option>" + val[i] + "</option>");
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = ["one", "two", "three"];
  var n = 1;
  $("button").click(function() {
    var select = $("select");
    //Remove all except first
    select.find('option:not(:first)').remove();

    //Append all in array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      select.append("<option>" + val[i] + "</option>");
    }
    n += 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

References

1. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
2. [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
3. [`:first` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Way more elegant solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var val=["one","two","three"];
  var n=0;
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("select").append("<option>"+val[n]+"</option>");
     n++; 
  });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e51mqfp7/

Comment: But `var n` **is** outside click event.

Comment: @Peachyz the iteration is based on the clicks, i.e., first click single iteration, second click two iteration and so on...

Comment: @Peachyz, got perfect way of the solution; +1 for it.

Comment: @Peachyz what if `val = [ "one" ]` and no iteration. Click multiple times??

Comment: @YSuraj Sorry.. I don't really understand what you mean by that. Can you provide an example case?

Comment: @Peachyz remove `var n=0` and `n++` from your code and check the result.

Comment: @YSuraj well.. everything in this code sample has a reason. That's why you shouldn't remove things

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting element by it's value, but when appending new `option` you do not set any value for it. Also first check if element does not exists and only than append, now your `$("select").not("one")` does not make sense (not mentioning that you misses `"` in selector)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = ["one", "two", "three"];
  var n = 1;
  $("button").click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if ($("select option[value='" + val[i] + "']").length == 0) {
        $("select").append("<option value='"+val[i]+"'>" + val[i] + "</option>");
      }
    }
    n += 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as OP wanted:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var val=["one","two","three"];
  var n=0;
  $("button").click(function(){
     for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
      if(i == n){
       $("select").not($("option[value='+val[i]+']")).append("<option>"+val[i]+"</option>");
     }
     } 
     n+=1; 
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/8dqjg7de/)